# Apache CXF: changing arg0 name to specific field name in XML (Java2WSDL)

Tags: java, spring, cxf, java2wsdl

How do I change arg0 from Apache CXF generated WSDL to something specific like "name"

```
// Fields
@WebParam(name="prgPregnancyIdPk")
@XmlElement(name = "prgPregnancyIdPk")
private String prgPregnancyIdPk;
```

I try to use **@XmlElement**, no effect. The generated WSDL uses arg0 still.

When I try to use **@WebParam** from **javax.ws.WebParam**, it says
"The annotation @WebParam is disallowed for this location"

This is frustrating Apache CXF!

I can go to the generated WSDL file and edit the param names but I don't think this is the best way to go.